# Filtering pandas dataframe groups based on groups comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove corrupted data from my pandas dataframe. I want to remove groups from dataframe that has difference of value bigger than one from the last group. Here is an example:

```
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      8 <- here number of group if I groupby by Value is larger than
7      8    the last groups number by 6, so I want to remove this
8      3    group from dataframe
9      3
```

Expected result:

```py
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      3
7      3
```

Edit:
jezrael solution is great, but in my case it is possible that there will be dubplicate group values:

```py
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      3
4      3
5      3
6      1
7      1
```

Sorry if I was not clear about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove duplicates for unique rows, then compare difference with shifted values and last filter by boolean indexing:

```
s = df['Value'].drop_duplicates()
v = s[s.diff().gt(s.shift())]

df = df[~df['Value'].isin(v)]
print (df)
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
8      3
9      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df[df['Value'].isin(df2.loc[~df2['Value'].gt(df2['Value'].shift(-1)), 'Value'].tolist())])
```

Output:

```
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
8      3
9      3
```

Comment: there will not always be a range between two groups of 2. So shift(2) is not effective.

Answer (score 0):

We can check if the difference is less than or equal to 5 *or* `NaN`. After we check  if we have duplicates and keep those rows:

```
s = df[df['Value'].diff().le(5) | df['Value'].diff().isna()]
s[s.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

---

```
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
8      3
9      3
```